# How to write pattern for preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string with some ampersands. For example a symbol "á" equivalency "&aacute;" in my string. But my function:

```
preg_replace("/(" . $q . ")+/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $c)
```

If the variable $q match any of this symbols "&aacute;" it is not an ampersand anymore and I get unreadable text.

How to write pattern which will ignore all symbols with are parts of ampersands?
Or pattern which ignore everything between "&" and ";".

It is the Czech language and I need to write a valid function to light keywords in a search results.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Could you explain more? What inputs make unwanted results?

Comment: Try `preg_quote($q)`. See http://php.net/manual/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of this problem

```
$str = html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$res = preg_replace("/(" . $q . ")+/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
```